# Could not load assembly MVVMCross

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a problem to load MVVMCross library loaded by NuGET (as N video suggest). This is my pluginloader:

```
        private void InitialisePlugins()
        {
            PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();

            Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
            Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
            Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
            Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
       }
```

Exception (seems that file is not loaded, but it's copied in directory output):

```
>     06-25 16:57:27.538 I/mvx     (  717):   4.21 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
>     mvx:Diagnostic:  4.21 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
>     [0:] mvx:Diagnostic:  4.21 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
>     06-25 16:57:27.611 I/mono-stdout(  717): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.21 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
>     [0:] 
>     06-25 16:57:27.708 I/mvx     (  717):   4.38 Setup: App start
>     mvx:Diagnostic:  4.38 Setup: App start
>     [0:] mvx:Diagnostic:  4.38 Setup: App start
>     06-25 16:57:27.788 I/mono-stdout(  717): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.38 Setup: App start
>     [0:] 
>     06-25 16:57:27.949 I/mvx     (  717):   4.62 Loading plugin assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll
>     mvx:Diagnostic:  4.62 Loading plugin assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll
>     06-25 16:57:28.028 I/mono-stdout(  717): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.62 Loading plugin assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll
>     [0:] mvx:Diagnostic:  4.62 Loading plugin assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll
>     Unhandled Exception:
>     
>     Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Loading...
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717): 
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717): Unhandled Exception:
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717): Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717): File name: 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid.dll'
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717):   at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence
> assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717):   at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717):   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717):   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString)
> [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717):   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Syst06-25 16:57:47.188 E/mono    (  717): 
> at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxFilePluginManager.LoadAssembly
> (System.Type toLoad) [0x0001e] in
> c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirr
>     The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0):

This post looks like a strange combination of nuget and non-nuget approaches. The error message would suggest that you haven't added the File plugin to your Android application project - have you?

---

Beyond that, since you have nuget setup and working, I think it might be useful if you follow through N=8 and N=9 in the N+1 videos - these talk about how to include and use plugins. See the index for these at http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/ - e.g:

- [N=8 : Location, Location, Location](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AomjbED9AzM&feature=ytfce) ([Blog Post](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n8-location-location-location-n1-days.html))

  - [**PCL Project**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=28s)
  - [Installing Location Plugin from NuGet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=76s)
  - [**Android Project**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=304s)
  - [Android Monitor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=597s)
  - [**iPhone Project**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=694s)
  - [**Windows Phone Project**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=882s)
  - [**Windows Store Project**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=1131s)
  - [Summery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AomjbED9AzM#t=1301s)

Comment: i have tried to delete all reference to my project and reloaded by nuget (as suggested in N8+, and how i have done before), but that doesn't solve my problem. How could i do?